# Ephemeral RSA key vs Ephemeral DH key?

Tags: java, security, ssl, encryption, applet

I try to design system that encrypts  files(audio) and store them in disc in order that only my clients(applet) decrypt and play them. So I decided to use AES cipher for bulk encryption and store keys in database. My problem is transferring secret key  securely.

In modern systems use SSL for transferring keys and data which are not stored cryptically. In [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL/TLS) design, session key is generated two ways;

First way client creates key and encrypt it server's public key(certificate). 
Second option is more secure and becomes more important after detecting [heartbleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) security bug. In this option key is created by client and server with [(EC)DHE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECDH) key agreement for every sessions.

When it comes to my case, there are two options as well.

First case;

1. Client(applet) can create ephemeral RSA key pair and sends public key to server.
2. Server encrypts secret key with client's public key and sends to client.
3. Client(applet) decrypt secret key with private key.
4. Client(applet) can decrypt audio files streamly and play.

Second case;

1. Client(applet) and server agrees on session key using (EC)DHE.
2. Server encrypts secret key symmetrically with session key and sends to client.
3. Client(applet) decrypt secret key with session key.
4. Client(applet) can decrypt audio files streamlly and play.

Which option is suits my scenario? What is pros and cons each case?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions are vulnerable to an active attacker, in position of man-in-the-middle, because the key exchange is not authenticated. This issue is solved in SSL/TLS by the use of the X.509 PKI. It could also be solved by giving your client prior knowledge of the server's public key, for example.
That being said, between your two options, go with the (EC)DHE one, because generating a new DH key from pre-computed DH group (also known as DH parameters) is fast, whereas generating a new RSA key is very slow.

Comment: Firstly thanks for reply. I want to control(know) who connects to server so that I create X.509 cert and import into applets. If I use (EC)DHE server and client must create key pair and server must create cipher and encrypt session key. Is this much costly?

Comment: Using DHE is very CPU-consuming, yes, but still less than generating a new RSA for each connection. You want to avoid that no matter what. ECDHE is really fast. You can see the benchmarks done by Vincent Bernat here: http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy.html